# Given a list, How to count items in that list?

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose I am giving this input a|dhg|shg|abc|oyi in python and want to get the count of given inputs. Please let me know how can I do this. 
I am new in python.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by splitting your `|` separated list , then count your items .

```
list = "a|dhg|shg|abc|oyi"
items = list.split("|")
count = len(items)
print count
```

Or simply in one line :

```
print len("a|dhg|shg|abc|oyi".split("|"))
```

Hope I helped

Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len()` to count input items. Try the code below

```
item = ['dhg', 'shg', 'abc', 'oyi']
print len(item)
```

Comment: Thanks Haresh. but with this, its counting every single character if we separate them with | symbol.